# How does google app engine determinge your monthly stored data usage?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, billing

Google app engine bills you for stored data on a monthly basis, but how does it determine how much to bill? Does it bill for the amount of data at the end of the month, or for the largest amount of data that has been stored at a point in time during that month? Or some other way?

Answer (score 1):

> For both free and paid applications, App Engine resets all resource measurements at the beginning of each calendar day (except for Stored Data, which always represents the amount of datastore storage in use). When free applications reach their quota for a resource, they cannot use that resource until the quota is replenished. Paid apps can exceed the free quota until their budget is exhausted.
>
> Daily quotas are replenished daily at midnight Pacific time. Per-minute quotas are refreshed every 60 seconds.

So it's daily. If you exceed your daily quota and don't have any more money in the budget then your app stops working.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Safety_Quotas_and_Billable_Quotas

Comment: yes, but not for stored data. Both datastore data and blobstore data would count towards your stored data.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure what you are asking then. When I look at the quota details for a free app I have 1 GB available in total for datastore, 5gb for bloblstore. I can't go over that for a free app, so I suppose the answer to your question is that if you go over X then you pay for that in addition to paying for X. Next month if you stay under X then you don't pay extra.

Comment: sorry, I was wrong, they don't both count towards stored data. I had a very old copy of the app engine docs stored on my pc, and I didn't know this had changed.

Comment: But the question remains, Let's say for example you enable billing. You have 1 gb of data in the datastore, and you add 3 gb to the datastore at the beginning of the month. During the month, you delete 2gb, and before the end of the month, you add another gb. will you be billed for 2gb above free quota now, because you have 3 in total, or for 3gb, since 4 is the largest ammount of data you've had during that month?

Comment: My understanding is that the bill will be calculated on a daily basis and you'll be charted accordingly but at the end of the month/billing cycle. So in your example, for the days you have X above free quota you'll pay Y. For the days you are below quota you'll pay nothing additional. So at the beginning of the month when you add 3GB of data you'll pay X every day you are over your free quota.

Comment: but the billing price is stated per month. Do they divide the monthly price by the number of days in the current month to get the price? And what about changes in data ammount during a day? Do they take the top ammount of data you've had at any point during this day?

Comment: They charge you per month, yes, but calculate it daily. The "top" amount of data on a given day would only be relevant if it exceeds your free quota, then you are paying extra. If you delete that data straight away you'll have still exceeded that limit for the day and would be charted.